# Why does the Yara-ma-yha-who live on fig trees?

Tags: mythical-creatures, folklore, indigenous-australian

The [Yara-ma-yha-who](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yara-ma-yha-who) is the indigenous Australian version of the vampire. It's a "little red man with a very big head, a large mouth with no teeth and suckers on the ends of its hands and feet" that lives on fig trees, drops down on unsuspecting travellers and drains their blood.

Why fig trees? What is it about them that makes them the ideal habitat for this fascinating creature?

Comment: Sounds to me like a vegetarian version of the beloved chupacabra!